# LINQ - Find index of a list item that has a null value

Tags: c#, list, linq

Some days ago I asked for a way to find columns with null values in a row list with Linq. Now I need to get the index of every found item and add it to a list and then show in a warning message later.

These are my row list and my null columns list.

```
var rowList = tablaExcel.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
var nullValues = rowList.Where(x => x.Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value)).ToList();
```

How can I get the index of any found item in the rowList.Where()? Just in case, I need the index of the rowList item, not of the nullValues item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select((x,i) => x.ItemArray.Select((y,j) => new {value = y, row = i, column = j} ).ToList();

Comment: lol if i had found the answer already i wouldn't post this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
 var indexes = rowList.Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
.Where(x => x.v.Any(y => y == null || y == DBNull.Value))
.Select(x => x.i);
```